# How can I manually look up a DataTemplate defined only by DataType, not key?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I'm trying to get the DataTemplate that will be used for a specific type.

I was under the impression that when you only specified the DataType, it implicitly uses that value as the key for that resource so the system can go look it up.

I attempted to test that with this code...

MainWindow.wpf:

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
        <Border x:Name="Bd"
            BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="6"
            Padding="6,4">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

... then I attempted the following, which fails...

```
var stringType = typeof(string);
var stringDataTemplate = this.FindResource(stringType);
```

So how can I programmatically retrieve a data type defined only by type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type is used as key for `Styles`, for `DataTemplates` you can construct a [`DataTemplateKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplatekey.aspx) from the type.

(As with the `DataType` in XAML you can pass an object for XML templating by tag name. You have to pass a type for CLR classes.)

Comment: Thanks!  That worked for finding the template.  However, I don't seem to be able to get it to properly expand out.  Specifically, the results of LoadContent() on the DataTemplate don't seem to respond to template-defined triggers.  Using the same template, I created two ContentPresenters.  One I simply set the content to an object of the correct data type and everything worked.  The second, I set the content to the results of the LoadContent() call and while the VisualTree did get correctly loaded, it was ignoring the triggers.  What am I missing?

Comment: @MarqueIV: I do not know. I for one would not do something like that and leave templates instantiation to the framework. Also i would suggest asking a separate question as it has nothing to do with the original one if you cannot resolve it.

Comment: We actually can't leave it to the framework.  A data-bound TabControl reuses its contents if it switches to another tab using the same data type so every time the tabs switch, it has to reinitialize itself with the new data.  We're trying to build a caching mechanism to bypass this feature.  And I originally did have this as another question containing both the finding and loading, but people kept saying to use a DataTemplateSelector, completely missing the point of what I was trying to do.  Still. You're right... You did answer at least this question so I'll mark it as such.

Comment: New question posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649665/how-can-you-programmatically-access-triggers-applied-via-a-datatemplate